# Changing Design of master template in Lotus Domino

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus, interop-domino

This question is specific to service account in Lotus domino.
Actually i am trying to access any user's calendar using another user credential via REST DAS services.
I have created one user in Domino and want to use this user to access the other user's calendar item.Is there any way i can achieve the same.
I have tried delegation of the access,but the problem with this is manually i have to go to each mailbox and do the same.Is there any way i can automate this process or changing a master template once so that it will reflect to all the users mail box.Any link/doc will help me.

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is. Do you need assistance in granting your technical user READ access to all mail files? Or do you need assistance with consuming calendar information using REST / DAS?

Answer (score 1):

You need to grant the user running your code access to the mail files.
In Domino Administrator you can change the ACL of multiple databases at the same time.

Comment: Thanks Thomas.It is not listing the user's database (<user>.nsf)>. Domino administrator ->Files tab->show me(Database only)->Manage ACL

Comment: Do you not see any databases in the files tab? hm..maybe you need more access

Comment: I am able to see databases , it is the user's DB.It is something else.(admin4.nsf,names.nsf,log.nsf....)

Comment: Not following, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Actually i am trying to access user calendar using REST based API provided by IBM DOmino.So for access any user's calendar you have to pass Basic Auth header of that user.In my application i don't have all the users credentials.So what i want is create one user in Domino and try to access the REST service using the same user .

Comment: yes ok, but I do not understand your comment: I am able to see databases , it is the user's DB.It is something else.(admin4.nsf,names.nsf,log.nsf....)

Comment: I am sorry i am not able to see user's DB,but apart from it i am able to see the(admin4.nsf,names.nsf,log.nsf....) .Is there any one nsf for all the user's DB?

Comment: In most cases all users mailfiles (nsf)  are under the "Mail" folder.

Comment: Also, be sure that you have connected the Domino Administrator client to the Domino server instead of looking at the list of local databases on the client machine.

Comment: Thanks Thomas and Richard.I am able to find all the users under mail folder.For any addition to the user is there anyway this permission can be automatically granted to them as well instead of doing manually.

Comment: You can write a script using Lotusscript or java that can update the ACL of all mail files.  just make sure the user running the script have access to change the ACL (Manager in the database)

Comment: Can you point me some link on the same.But this will only do the changes for the existing user's mailbox ,what about if a new user is getting added in that case?