# Passing iCal using Notes API for Java

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus, interop-domino

I am using Lotus Domino 9.0.1. I want integrate Domino with my application.Is there any API(method) for passing the iCal using Notes API.Usecase what i am trying is all the CRUD opertions on normal as well as Recurrence meeting.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways to create a calendar event from iCalendar input:  1) You can use the Notes Java back-end classes -- specifically the [NotesCalendar.createEntry()](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_CREATEENTRY_METHOD_CAL_JAVA.html) method, or 2) You can use the REST calendar API -- specifically [calendar events POST](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20Domino%20Access%20Services%209.0.1#action=openDocument&res_title=Calendar_events_POST&content=apicontent).

You can do all the other CRUD operations with both the back-end classes and REST.  One advantage of REST is that it works "remotely".  Your application doesn't need Notes or Domino installed locally to use the REST API.  Based on your other questions on StackOverflow, I think you want to use the REST API.

Comment: Thanks Dave.I am trying different options.Yes i know i can do it using REST apis but the problem is i don't have user credentials(password) at application end.Is it possible to create one user or service account and by that i can able to access all user's calendar items.

Comment: Yes.  You can: 1) create an identity for your application, 2) add that identity to the ACL for all mail files, and 3) authenticate each REST request as the application.  There's more info about step 2 here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29093468/changing-design-of-master-template-in-lotus-domino

Comment: Thanks Dave.I tried giving in the ACL for all the mail files in bulk but the challenge in that is if we are adding or on boarding  some new users then again i have to go to individual user and give those permission.Is there anyway i can change in some template and it will be delegated across all the users.

Comment: Yes.  You would need to change the ACL in the master mail template.  See this answer for more details:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/29260162/1192402

Comment: Thanks Dave. Is it possible to get some consultants for implementing different usecases.