# Manage ACL for the entire users in domino

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Is it be possible to have a common ACL rule to the list of users? basically this rule will be for the mail access (read and write documents with no access)).We would able to achieve it my managing the ACL at a point of time. But later if any new user is onboarded, is it possible to force to be  with the same ACL. Suggestions please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution in detail.

First of all create the user who acts as a service account.
In domino administrator configuration--> files --> select the users apart from the service account. Right click --> manage --> manage ACL.

Add the service account user there. select person (right side combo box 1) No access (combo box 2). Select the 2 check boxes below(read and write options).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a set of standard ACL entries you can do so by creating ACL entries in the design template with names in square brackets.

For example an entry named [StandardUsers] in the ACL of the template will result in an entry named StandardUsers (presumably a group) with the same roles and access level in any new database based on that template.

Such an addition to the ACL of the template will not affect existing databases.

Comment: Can you please forward some links for the same. Is there any other alternative for this?

Comment: Why do you need an alternative? This is EXACTLY how it is meant by IBM. Here is a [link](http://www.matnewman.com/webs/personal/matblog.nsf/dx/tip-of-the-day-automatically-populate-acls-of-new-databases-by-changing-the-templates-acl) to a site, where this is described with screenshots

Comment: An alternative would be to write code to maintain the ACLs. But it´s better practice to use templates and groups. Could you expand the question with an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @TorstenLink :- Thanks for the reply.The link is not working. If we change the ACL in master template, will ACL  get updated for the existing users?

Comment: @Martin Plantener Jensen :- We have a webapp configured with microsoft exchange. Exchange has rest APIs, Service account, and a notification component which helped to sync with the local database and  pulling calendar for any other user.Now our requirement is to replace exchange with domino. Struggling to do this because of the 3 features above mentioned is not at all with Domino. ) create a deligated user to access other user's calendar (read and write documents with no access). 2) get notification from the domino for any changes in meeting through any other channel

Comment: Your second requirement is discussed here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294699/ibm-lotus-domino-calendar-getting-real-time-updates)

Comment: If you get notifications by inserting code on the server (as suggested there), your access requirement is also solved: Simply sign and run the code under the name (and authority) of the server.