# IBM Lotus Domino Calendar Getting Real Time updates

Tags: calendar, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, domino-designer-eclipse

I want to get any changes in the Appointment for users and Room Resources from IBM domino calendar. Our Application integrate with Domino through Rest Services. Now , if any changes in Calendar & Scheduling for User or Room Resources through some other application, then we want to show those updates in real time in our application. What is the best way to do this? Tried lot of documents but still unsure of the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no equivalent in the Notes/Domino APIs to the notification services that are available in Exchange Web Services. So I think you would have to build this from scratch, using the Notes C API's Extension Manager feature to build a server-side module that tracks updates to calendar events and sending notifications to your application.

Comment: Or an agent, based on TriggerHappy?

Comment: Yes, that's an option. A server task would have a lot less overhead though, and it could likely do a much better job of real-time handling in cases where appointments are added to many calendars in a very short time. Also, I guess it depends on what type of application is wanting to get notified. If it's a client-side app and since agents aren't running full time, the alerts would have to be pushed out to clients, so there would have to be some mechanism for clients to register so that the agent would know when and how to send the alert, whereas a server task could be listening for client conn

Comment: Thanks @RichardSchwartz. I am newbie to Domino. We have used Java Rest services to do CRUD operations in calendar. You have any code sample that points to the Notes C API's Extension Manager feature to build a server-side module that tracks updates to calendar events and sending notifications it would be great. Can you please point me to any code samples or any other documentation around it.

Comment: Extension Manager and C API are very advanced Notes develoment techniques, that are probably beyond what a newbie should be working with. I've done several Extension Manager projects over the yeras, but I'm not aware of many samples - certainly  none that would actually show tracking calendar events and sending notificaitons. That's  pretty specific applicaiton.

Comment: However, if you want to learn about what Extesntion manager can do, so you can figure out for yourself how to use it to build a notificaiton service, then I advise reading about it in the C API documentation, and also downloading and working with the code from OpenNTF's TriggerHappy project.

Comment: Thanks @RichardSchwartz. If we could get some consultants who could help us with the extension manager and notification service that also would be great. I tried but not getting consultants in my region. Any pointers of consultants also would be great.

Comment: If you want to discuss consultants, please contact me off of StackOverflow. You can find my info on the contact page of http://www.rhs21.com.